# Nessus vs OWASP Dependency Check

Tags: security, owasp, nessus

I would like to ask about the difference between Nessus and OWASP Depencence Check. My understanding is that Nessus includes the functionality of Dependency Cherck, Is that right ?

Answer (score 4):

Nessus works a little bit different than OWASP DC. OWASP DC looks at your buildfiles and compares them against a database of known vulnerabilites of the used libraries. Nessus does an active scan against a running appplication, network, database, etc.

But depending on the point of view one could say Nessus includes the functionality of OWASP DC as it should find at least the same vulnerabilities as DC. :-)